# Apache Mobile Filter consuming large memory then consuming swap

Tags: apache-2.2

I installed and configured Apache Mobile Filter module for Apache to redirect users to mobile version of our website (AMF51DegreesFilter)

At the beginning everything looks ok.
As far as the number of request grows, the number of used memory too. But the usage of memory does not stabilize. After some time system starts using swap, more and more swap.

I try options:
PerlSetEnv AMFDeepParse 3
PerlSetEnv AMFProductionMode true

Nothing helps.

Any potential solution??

Comment: which is your configuration ? Apache
mod_perl version
httpd.conf

Comment: Hi, I use: apache2 2.2.16-6+squeeze8, libapache2-mod-perl2 2.0.4-7